# Posting JS variable from HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

Im a bit of a newbie.

Im trying to post some data I have in a JavaScript variable to my server.

Iv looked around and from what I gather I need to put it in as part of a form? is there anyway to hide this form box?

Do I place this information in the value section of the form?

Eg.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Namespace</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        functionAddPostData(){

        var name = "Christopher";
        var last = "Bar";

       var formInfo = document.forms['info'];

       name = formInfo.elements["first"].innerHTML;
        last = formInfo.elements["surname"].innerHTML;

      }</script>

     </head>
     <body>
     <form action="script.php" method="post" allign="bottom">
        <label for="info"> 
            <input type="text" name="first" value="" size ="40" />
        <input type="text" name="surname" value="" size ="60" />
            <input type= "submit" name="submitted" value="info" allign="middle"/>

     </form>  
     </body>
     </html>
```

This is my best guess? Am I heading in the right direction? Is there a way to hide the form boxes?

Comment: headed the right way, are you trying to validate the data? if so you have to add an onsubmit to your form tag to run your function when u sebmit the form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use hidden fields to post the data to server if you dont want to show the textbox in the UI.

```
<input type="hidden" name="first" value="" size ="40" />
```

You should set the onSubmit of form to functionAddPostData which will get called when you submit the form. Also the form should have a name atttibute since you are trying to access it by name.

The form element values should be set as below

```
var formInfo = document.forms['info'];

formInfo.first.value = name;
formInfo.surname.value = last;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things wrong with the code you posted, which is why its not working. It's late so instead of a line by line analysis I will post a modified version that you can look over. I would recommend reading through an HTML guiide like [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) and to also go through a good javascript tutorial (like [Webmonkey](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/javascript_tutorial_-_lesson_1/). Cheers.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Namespace</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function AddPostData(){

    var name = "Christopher";
    var last = "Bar";

   var formInfo = document.forms['info'];

   name = formInfo.elements["first"].value;
    last = formInfo.elements["surname"].value;

  alert(name + ' ' + last);

  }</script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="info" action="script.php" method="post" align="bottom">
    <p>For</p> 
        <input type="text" name="first" value="" size ="40" />
    <input type="text" name="surname" value="" size ="60" />
        <input type= "submit" name="submitted" value="info" align="middle" onclick="AddPostData();"/>

 </form>  
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks Perception. Il definatly look into the online tutes! I tried your code however it doesnt seem to place the variables into the form box or into the alert. Il keep looking though.

Comment: The code I have above is for extracting the values from the form inputs and posting them as an alert. Of course you can also submit the data to the server, as Ajax or any other means you see fit. Were you looking to do the opposite (populate form values from server data)?